# No internet connection after booting - 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, internet

Randomly, after booting Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I have no internet connection with ethernet.
I have a dual boot with Windows 7 (that I would like to avoid) and there is no problem with windows...
Thanks in advance for any piece of an advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this also, except it only occurs when I press enter when in settings display, wanting to speed up boot process. If I allow the system to boot Ubuntu after the several seconds wait period, Ubuntu boots with my Internet connected, working fine. Also, with my dual boot system, if I use the down arrow to highlight&select Windows 10, and then press Enter, the system boots Windows 10 fine. Sometimes with Internet connected, sometimes without but there is always the easy UI tool to reconnect available. Apparently, when pressing Enter in the system setting menu when booting Ubuntu, it boots but the UI does not presenting the Internet UI icon and drop down in the upper right corner. I am a Linux newcomer, turning to Linux some thirty years after working with a Sun Unix OS.

Comment: That's probably due to some kind of hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on connections symbol (top-right, near sound) and see if the wired connection is connected. If it is not connected, check for loose cables.
2. Open terminal and run

`ifconfig -a`

Check if it is showing an IP address. Please share this output as it may help in troubleshooting.

3. Try `ping 8.8.8.8`

If reply is received, then you are connected to internet. There may be DNS issue, move to next step for further troubleshooting. If request time out comes, try the following command:

`traceroute 8.8.8.8`

and see if you are getting past your default gateway. Share this output too.

4. If you were able to ping in step 3, try:

`nslookup google.com`

If you are getting IP in response, check the browser proxy settings (in case any proxy is enabled, remove it and then try).

If request timed out comes, then go to edit connections ->wired connection-> ipv4 settings and manually add dns servers (you can add google dns IPs (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) and then try.